# SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I am sending POST Request with API in JavaScript and I have already made many POST Requests with this following method but now this is showing the error:
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0**

Here is my code-

```
function updateAlertSetting(data_json, callback){

var firebase_token = getCookie("firebase_token");
if(firebase_token===null){
    window.location.href="login.html";
    return;
}
var base_64_firebase_token = btoa(firebase_token);

console.log(typeof data_json);  // Object
console.log(data_json);         // prints the data_json

$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: getApiURL(28),
        data: {
                "alertSetting_value": data_json.alertSetting_value,
                "alertSetting_name": data_json.alertSetting_name,
                "firebase_token": data_json.firebase_token
              },
        headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + base_64_firebase_token },
        success : function(newData){
            callback(newData);
        },
        error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
            console.log(throwError);
            console.log("Error!!!");
        }
    }
);
}
```

Comment: Check devtools network tab to check request/response data

Comment: You should definitely post your response

Comment: @0xc14m1z I am already doing POST Request. Please see that.

Comment: @jro What do you want to check or what should I tell you more about the problem?

Comment: Go to the network tab of devtools, find the request and add the response code and response data (if any) to your question

Comment: I found this that the API is working and it changed something in the backend but callback data is not working and API responds the **newData** as **Success** String.

Answer (score 0):

I did by this following code:

```
var xmlhttp;
    try{
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                //Browser doesn't support ajax  
                alert("Your browser is unsupported");
            }
        }
    }       
    if(xmlhttp){
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200) {
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            if(xmlhttp.status === 404){
                alert("It couldn't connect to the server.");
            }               
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",getApiURL(28),true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + base_64_firebase_token);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("alertSetting_value="+data_json.alertSetting_value+"&alertSetting_name="+data_json.alertSetting_name+"&firebase_token="+data_json.firebase_token);
    }
```

Now this is working and thanks @jro.